# How could I use external storage to save my values on a form, create a new entry in a leader board, and be able to pull the data back?

Tags: java, android-external-storage

I'm fairly new to Java, as I've been working with it for less than a year, and am not sure how to go about this.

I have my code that starts to save the values, but I need it to create a new entry in a list.

```
 public void setupSaveButton() {
    Button save = findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calculateTotal();
            getTeamNumber();
            getMatchNumber();
            //output the total to leaderboard where it saves and ranks them

            //save the data to a list in the leaderboard
        }
    });
}
```

For example, in the mobile notepad app in either iOS or Android, when you save a note, it creates a new visual in the menu. It has your title and other things but I don't know how to create XML widgets and assign them IDs and where they should go. I'm sorry for rambling on about this, as I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I don't know what it is. The code where I save it isn't pictured above as it would be way too big.

Comment: Partially, mainly creating objects for my xml file when save is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this official Android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteExternalStorage); it is quite helpful. It shows how to setup your project to write and read files to and from external storage, and also how to setup your files.

Then, [here's another tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/9400/android-external-storage-read-write-save-file). It's shown that once you have gotten your file, you can write it to storage like this:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
    fos.write(yourValuesAsString.getBytes()); // Convert any values you want to store into strings before writing to files
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And read it from storage like this:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        myData = myData + strLine;
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will be applying this to my code but I still don't know how to create xml objects when save is pressed.

Comment: What kind of XML object do you want to create?

Comment: A small section of items; 2 or 3 textviews and a button

Comment: Would it be better to use internal storage than external storage?